# ::after selector not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

::after selector not displaying properly.

I'm trying to create the same background effect like **[this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJOpXr)** for my other **[code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgXmNP)**, instead it displays like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf8W8.jpg)**.

CSS:

```
label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 233px;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}


label::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;   
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}


input:focus + label::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, -1.9, 1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

input:focus + label > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translate3d(0, -80%, 0);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
}
```

Comment: please post the html code also ... you did the effort to put the CSS, so continue the same with the html and create a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fixed code. I think this will help you..

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}


label {
  font-family: monospace; 
  font-size: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 0; 
}

span {
  transition: transform 1s .2s;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -33px;
  display: block;
  padding: .6em 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.username {
position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px; /* input field width */
}


input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height:34px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  border:0px;

} 

input:focus {
  outline: 1;
}

/*
input:focus { 
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); 
transition: width 5s; 
transition-delay: 3s; 
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1); 
z-index: -1; 
background: green; 
} */


label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 233px;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}


label::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;   
  transform: scale3d(1, 0.2, 1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}


input:focus + label::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, -1.9, 1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <p class="head">Sign In</p>
<form>

    <div class="username"> 
      
      <input type="text" name="name" class="input-field" id="user"/> <!--input filed-->
      <label for="user"><span>Username</span></label>
    </div> 
  
</form>

</body>
</html
```